# What is the chinese kanji for yin-hoa?

Tags: meaning, glyph-origin

What is the kanji for yin-hoa (all the colors of the rainbow) and its prononciation ?
It is used as a name for a person.

And what would be a more complete or alternative meaning of it ? and its origin ?

Comment: 天虹 /Tiānhóng/ is rainbow

Comment: "yin-hoa" doesn't sound like rainbow, it sounds like the milky way galaxy (銀河).

Comment: Could also be 霓虹（ní hóng,  Rainbow/Neon） which sounds quite near.

Comment: @dROOOze Why not an answer instead of a comment ?

Comment: @TangHo Close to SeniorTame's answer, but why does it sound so different than yinhoa ?

Comment: may be it was 'tinhao' instead of 'yinhoa' (t and y are right next to each other on the keybroad)

Comment: @TangHo I did not mistype. /Tiānhóng/ became tinhao ?

Comment: Another possibility: 煙花 _yānhuā_ a rather poetic word for "fireworks", but originally meaning "the flowers of spring", and extended in metaphorical use for various colourful scenes.

Comment: @Michaelyus SOunds good, why not making an answer rather than a comment ?

Answer (score 2):

## 虹

Original meaning: *n.* Rainbow

Extended meanings:

- *n.* bridge (the shape of rainbow looks like a bridge) *e.g.* 虹桥 长虹卧波 断虹 跨虹
- *adj.* colorful or color-related *e.g.* 虹裳 虹辉 虹光 虹膜 虹玉
- *adj.* attractive *e.g.* 虹女 虹霓吐颖
- *adj.* imposing *e.g.* 气势如虹 虹泉 气吞虹蜺 气贯长虹 虹楼 虹陛
- *adj.* bright *e.g.* 虹星
- *n.* flag (rarely used) *e.g.* 虹采 虹旍

Origin:

> It's a pictographic kanji in oracle bone script, the ancients saw the rainbow as a two-headed creature (1st image). It evolved into a semantic-phonetic compound kanji in seal script: 虫 is used to express its meaning (insect), and 工 is used to express its sound (2nd image).
>
> [image] [image] *(image credit to wiktionary)*

---

A kanji that is often used in names, more often used by female names, *e.g. (All listed here are the names of Chinese celebrities)* 翁虹 潘虹樾 潘虹 陶虹 赵虹乔 倪虹洁, relatively less used in male names, but not absolutely none, *e.g.* 李虹辰 曾虹畅 are the names of male celebrities.

Comment: Great great. And about the prononciation ?

Comment: Is it just /hóng/ ? if so, /yin/ is missing..

Comment: @Soleil it could be the 霓虹 mentioned in a previous comment.  although the standard way to write it in english letters is "ni hong", listening with an english ear can easily make the first part sound like yin and perhaps the individual speaker did not emphasize the ng at the end. both characters can mean rainbow/rainbow related things. I can't think of any other characters meaning rainbow that are similar sounding.

Comment: Agree with @zagrycha , just adding two cents: 霓 refers to secondary bows, and 虹 refers to primary bows. When used together, the original meaning is still rainbows, but with an extended meaning: in internet slangs, 霓虹 refers to Japan (as it sounds close to にほん). In daily life, 霓虹 is most often used with 灯 to form 霓虹灯(neon light).

Comment: Very interesting. Could 霓虹 also mean polymath or universal person like Leonardo DaVinci ?

Comment: @SeniorTame often 霓 in compound terms is rainbows itself.  so I think it counts for regular use over all.  fun barely related fact: there are always two rainbows, but the second usually isn't visible because of the background color being too light etc.

Comment: @Soleil no there are not any definitions of these characters related to those things.  霓 can also be a rosy/peachy colored cloud in poetic speech and 虹 is only rainbow in common use-- these are not cohnting compound vocabulary of course :)

Comment: I'm not sure why this was deleted, but deleting it would leave the question unanswered.